# FileWriter not writing to .txt file

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the "test" or whatever to be printed out inside a file called `doctor.txt`.

Whenever I run the program, it just comes out to be blank on the file. Also, do you have to make the .txt in the folder beforehand, or does it automatically make the file for you?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Vowels {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            int countA = 0;
            int countE = 0;
            int countI = 0;
            int countO = 0;
            int countU = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("poetry.txt"));
        String poetry = "";

        while(in.hasNext()){
            poetry = in.nextLine();
            poetry = poetry.replaceAll(" ", "~");
            System.out.println(poetry);

            for(int v = 0; v < poetry.length(); v++) {
                if(poetry.charAt(v) == 'a') {
                    countA++;
                }
                if(poetry.charAt(v) == 'e') {
                    countE++;
                }
                if(poetry.charAt(v) == 'i') {
                    countI++;
                }
                if(poetry.charAt(v) == 'o') {
                    countO++;
                }
                if(poetry.charAt(v) == 'u') {
                    countU++;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The number of 'A's is: " + countA);
        System.out.println("The number of 'E's is: " + countE);
        System.out.println("The number of 'I's is: " + countI);
        System.out.println("The number of 'O's is: " + countO);
        System.out.println("The number of 'U's is: " + countU);
        FileWriter doctor = new FileWriter("doctor.txt");
        doctor.write("test");
    }
    catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not closing or flushing the `FileWriter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `doctor.close();` after `doctor.write("test");`.

Comment: Let close the doctor :) I don't know why and who downvoted this guy's answer ?? However I agreed with @Subhrajyoti Majumder but its just a comment there should be answer as well...@eclideria its good to provide more explanation that why you want to close Dr. :) I am upvoting